# Make column values to new columns and fill it will another columns, If the value not present, replace with zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:

```
col1     col2     col3
a         ex1      102
a         ex2      25
a         ex3      50
a         ex4      66
b         ex2      45
b         ex5      20
c         ex1      30
```

I want col2 valus to be the new columns and the col3 valus will be the values like following:

```
col1  ex1   ex2    ex3    ex4    ex5
 a    102    25     50     66     0
 b     0     45      0     0      20
 c     30    0       0      0     0
```

If the value is not present, It will be zero like the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index='col1', columns='col2', values='col3', fill_value=0).reset_index()

col2    col1    ex1    ex2  ex3    ex4  ex5
0       a       102    25   50     66   0
1       b       0      45   0      0    20
2       c       30     0    0      0    0
```

Comment: Thanks, Any idea how to reset columns like for this example, The columns will be:
col1, ex1, ex2, ex3, ex4, ex5